# Mysterious problem with ps2pdf in texlive 2013

Tags: beamer, pstricks, ps2pdf

The following code comiled fine in texlive 2012, but gives me an error now:

```
Error: /typecheck in --restore--
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   502.75   80.6952   512.75   80.6952   507.661   138.665   497.661   138.665   138.665
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1839   11   5   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1823   11   5   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1164/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:123/200(L)--   --dict:182/300(L)--   --dict:86/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
Current file position is 136214
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

What can be done about this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}


\begin{document}



\frame[shrink]{
\begin{pspicture}(-0.4,0.8)(21.2,13.4)

\rput[B](18.5,1){\rnode{verbtrace}{[ \_ ]}}

\rput[B](18.5,3){\rnode{vverbtrace}{V}}\nput[labelsep=2pt,ref=t]{0}{vverbtrace}{\!/\!/V}%


\ncdiag{vverbtrace}{verbtrace}


\end{pspicture}


}


\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

This is the full example with correct positioning and sensible shrinking and resizing. LaTeX ok, but ps2pdf complains:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}

\newcommand<>{\rot}[1]{{\color#2{red!75!black}#1}}
\newcommand<>{\gruen}[1]{{\color#2{green!60!black}#1}}

\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}


\begin{document}



\frame[shrink]{
\frametitle{Eine Beispielanalyse}
\parskip0pt
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=5.4mm}
%
\begin{pspicture}(-0.4,0.8)(21.2,13.4)
%\psgrid

\only<5-6,10-11>{
\pscurve[%showpoints=true,%
linecolor=green,arrows=<->](4.2,9.8)(7.725,11)(13,10)(16.4,7.6)(17.2,5.6)(16.6,3.6)
}

\rput[B](1,1){\rnode{zzm}{zum zweiten Mal}}
\rput[B](5,1){\rnode{dw}{die Weltmeisterschaft}}
\rput[B](8,1){\rnode{spurvf}{[ \_ ]}}

\rput[B](11,1){\rnode{errang}{errang}}

\rput[B](15,1){\rnode{clark}{Clark}}

\rput[B](16.5,1){\rnode{extractiontrace}{[ \_ ]}}

\rput[B](18.5,1){\rnode{verbtrace}{[ \_ ]}}

\rput[B](16.5,3){\rnode{vextractiontrace}{V}}\nput[labelsep=2pt]{0}{vextractiontrace}{\only<6-8>{\sliste{ \textit{nom} }}}
\nput[labelsep=2pt]{0}{vextractiontrace}{\only<9-11>{\!/\!/\gruen{V}\sliste{\textit{nom}}}}
\nput[labelsep=0pt]{0}{vextractiontrace}{\only<5>{/\!/\gruen{V}}}

\rput[B](18.5,3){\rnode{vverbtrace}{V}}\nput[labelsep=2pt,ref=t]{0}{vverbtrace}{\only<2>{\!/\!/\rot{V}}}%
\nput[labelsep=2pt]{0}{vverbtrace}{\only<8->{\sliste{ \textit{nom}, V/\!/\gruen{V} }}}


\rput[B](17,5){\rnode{vkomplex}{V}}\nput[labelsep=2pt]{0}{vkomplex}{\only<2>{\!/\!/\rot{V}}}%
\nput[labelsep=2pt]{0}{vkomplex}{\only<8->{\sliste{ \textit{nom} }}}
\rput[B](15,5){\rnode{npclark}{NP[\textit{nom}]}}

\rput[B](16,7){\rnode{vp}{VP}}\nput[labelsep=0pt]{0}{vp}{\only<2>{/\!/\rot{V}}}

\rput[B](11,3){\rnode{verrang}{\gruen<7-11>{V}}}

\rput[B](11,5){\rnode{errang_mvf_lr}{\rot<2>{V}}}
\nput[labelsep=2pt]{0}{errang_mvf_lr}{\only<7-11>{\sliste{ \alt<8->{\textit{nom}}{\ldots},  V/\!/\gruen{V} }}}

\rput[B](11,7){\rnode{errang_v1_lr}{V}}\nput[labelsep=2pt,ref=B]{0}{errang_v1_lr}{\only<2>{\sliste{ VP/\!/\rot{V} }}}

\rput[B](12.5,9){\rnode{vp2}{VP}}


\rput[B](8,5){\rnode{vspurvf}{V}}\nput[labelsep=2pt]{0}{vspurvf}{\only<3>{\sliste{ \textit{nom}, \textit{acc} }}}%
\nput[labelsep=0pt]{0}{vspurvf}{\only<4-5,11>{/\!/\gruen{V}}}
%
\rput[B](5,5){\rnode{np_dw}{NP[\textit{acc}]}}

\rput[B](6.5,7){\rnode{v'_vf}{V$'$}}\nput[labelsep=2pt]{0}{v'_vf}{\only<3>{\sliste{ \textit{nom} }}}%
\nput[labelsep=0pt]{0}{v'_vf}{\only<4-5,11>{/\!/\gruen{V}}}

\rput[B](1,7){\rnode{pp_zzm}{PP}}

\rput[B](3.25,9){\rnode{v'_vf_2}{V$'$}}\nput[labelsep=2pt]{0}{v'_vf_2}{\only<3,6>{\sliste{ \textit{nom} }}}%
\nput[labelsep=0pt]{0}{v'_vf_2}{\only<4-5,11>{/\!/\gruen{V}}}

\rput[B](7.725,12){\rnode{vp3}{VP}}

\pstriangle(1,1.8)(2.8,4.9)
\pstriangle(5,1.8)(3.4,2.9)

\psset{angleA=-90,angleB=90,arm=0pt}

\ncdiag{vextractiontrace}{extractiontrace}
\ncdiag{vverbtrace}{verbtrace}

\ncdiag{vkomplex}{vextractiontrace}
\ncdiag{vkomplex}{vverbtrace}

\ncdiag{npclark}{clark}
\ncdiag{vp}{npclark}
\ncdiag{vp}{vkomplex}

\ncdiag{verrang}{errang}
\alt<7>{
\ncline[linecolor=red,arrows=->]{verrang}{errang_mvf_lr}
}{
\ncdiag{errang_mvf_lr}{verrang}
}
\alt<2>{
\ncline[linecolor=red,arrows=->]{errang_mvf_lr}{errang_v1_lr}
}{
\ncdiag{errang_v1_lr}{errang_mvf_lr}
}

\ncdiag{vp2}{errang_v1_lr}
\ncdiag{vp2}{vp}

\ncdiag{vspurvf}{spurvf}
\ncdiag{v'_vf}{vspurvf}
\ncdiag{v'_vf}{np_dw}

\ncdiag{v'_vf_2}{pp_zzm}
\ncdiag{v'_vf_2}{v'_vf}

\ncdiag{vp3}{v'_vf_2}
\ncdiag{vp3}{vp2}


\end{pspicture}
}
\small
\pause
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Verbbewegung im Kernsatz wie erklärt: Lexikonregel lizenziert V1-Verb
\item Kombination von Elementen in der Vorfeldprojektion ganz normal
\item Da Kopf im VF eine V-Spur ist, werden V-Informationen nach oben gegeben.
\item VF-Projektion steht zu Extraktionsspur im VK in Beziehung \only<6>{(auch Valenz)}
\pause
\item Mult-VF-LR lizenziert Verb, das eine Spur plus deren Argumente selegiert.
\item Dieses steht in Verbletztstellung und bildet einen Komplex.
\end{itemize}


}


\end{document}
```

Comment: does it work if you add `\usepackage{pst-ovl}` to the preamble?

Answer (score 2):

I have no problem with an up-to-date TeXLive when *not* using the shrink option:

```
 \begin{frame}%[shrink]
 \framtetitle
  ...
 \end{frame}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make the example more minimal before submitting it and it actually did not cause a problem any longer. I added back in [shrink] and this may be the cause for the problem.

Comment: Well yes. This slide was a complex slide with a lot of stuff in the figure and a lot of text below it. I will add the full slide and I hope it does make some sense =:-).